# Next JS - Show modal based on query param just on first page load

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to show modal on first page load based on query param existence and not to show it again when user refresh the page, how should I handle it?(query param is changeable)
I have tried it by set cookie but not work fine.

Comment: can you show a working code of what you tried? So everyone could know what exactly to help you with. Thanks

Comment: when the user refreshes the page, will the query param still be in the url that is being reloaded?

Comment: maybe user never refresh the page, and change the route. but I want to handle it if refreshed, not open modal again

Comment: Actually its a form that after submit its redirected to ipg, and after successful payment, redirect to first page with query param.

Comment: I tried answering your question the best way I could without seeing your code. Probably it might not be exactly what you needed but you can get the idea and apply it to your case. You can ask if something still isn't clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as I understand you want the following:

1. Open a modal based on a query string.
2. Not open the modal if already opened.

Lets say that the url is `www.mysite.com/payment?paymentStatus=success&paymentId=111`

```
import { withRouter, Link } from 'react-router';
import queryString from 'query-string';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';// Haven't tried it but probably works from the repo
import Modal from 'some-modal-library';

const cookies = new Cookies();

const PaymentHandler = (props) => {
    const {paymentStatus, paymentId} = queryString.parse(props.location.search) || {};
    console.log(params); // {paymentStatus: 'success', paymentId: '111'}
    const openModal = paymentStatus && paymentStatus === 'success' ? true : false;

    if (openModal) {
        // Check if stored in cookies based on the paymentId previously
        const paymentStatusFromCookie = cookies.get(paymentId);
        if (paymentStatusFromCookie && paymentStatusFromCookie === 'success') {
            // This means we've already set it. Just return null or react fragment
            // This will not render the modal on the DOM
            return <></>;
        }

        // Else set the cookie and allow the modal render
        cookies.set(paymentId, paymentStatus, { path: '/' });
    }

    return (
        <Modal
            open={openModal}
        >
            <h2>Your payment was successful</h2>
            {/*Reroute to another page once close to even avoid refresh in the first place*/}
            <Link to="/" />Close</Link>
        </Modal>
    )
}

export default withRouter(PaymentHandler);
```